# How is it possible my ReactJS component alternates between my old state and my new state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

I have put a console.log in the render() function.

I'm using setState() inside a function. Then my component update but immediately after I can check that the state come back to the old state.

**edit:** now my problem is to display the state properly when extands, the rest works honorably I think.

Here my sandbox: 
https://codesandbox.io/s/77ymmnpr1

In my code I'm creating three labels that are expandable, then I put some labelComponent to overlaying them. The overlay got a button to come back on the menu. The problem is that when I then expand an another labelComponent, there is a slight lag with the old state then the new state displayed. Hence the console.log I'm providing to you.

That put something like following in the console:

> ```
> PATHNAME: newState
> PATHNAME: oldState
> PATHNAME: newState
> PATHNAME: oldState
> ```

**edit:** now my console returns on second rendering:

> stateOne
>
> ```
> currentState
> ```

then, on third rendering:

> stateOne
>
> ```
> stateTwo
>
> currentState
> ```

on fourth rendering:

> ```
> stateOne
>
> stateTwo
>
> stateThree
>
> currentState
> ```

What that mean? I call this.setState() only to put in it the new state, so why it come back to the old state?

Here my react.js code:

```
export default class Label extends Component {

  state={ 
    labelStock:[],

    sequence:undefined,
    labelToRemove:[],
    pathname:"",
    displayLabel:false,

    displayFreshFood:false,
    displayLocalFarm:false,
    displayBeerQuality:false
  }

  componentDidMount(){   
      this.setLabelArray()
  }

  shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {  
    let {pathname}= nextState   
    console.log("NEXTSTATE: ", pathname) 
    if(this.state.pathname !== nextState.pathname){ 
        if((
          pathname.includes("freshfood") ||
          pathname.includes("localfarm") ||
          pathname.includes("beerquality") ) && this.state.labelToRemove.length >0
          ){  
            this.setState({displayLabel:true})
          }
          else if(this.state.displayLabel !== nextState.displayLabel){ 
            this.setState({displayLabel:false})            
          }  

          return true
    }    
    else if(this.state.displayLabel !== nextState.displayLabel){ 
        return true 
    }

    return false
  }
  setLabelArray=()=>{ 
    let labelArray=[]

    labelStock.forEach(function (item) {
      labelArray.push(item.name);
    });

    this.setState({labelStock:labelArray})
  }

  renderLabel=()=>(
    labelStock.map((item, index) =>{

      return ( 
        <div 
          ref={item.name}
          key={index}
          style={{backgroundImage: `url(${item.image})`}}
          className={this.state.labelToRemove.includes(item.name) ? `${style.label_container} ${style.label_to_remove}` : style.label_container}
        >
          <div  
          style={{display: this.state.displayLabel ? 'none' : 'initial' }}
          onClick={() => this.expand(item.name)} 
          className={style.more_info_button}> 
              <img  src={moreInfoButton} alt=""/> 
          </div>
          <div id={style.label_item} > Here some text</div>
        </div>
      )
  })
)

  expand=(item)=>{ 

    console.log("IN EXPAND")
    let removeItem= this.state.labelStock.filter(word => word!== item);
    this.setState({
      labelToRemove:removeItem,
      displayLabel:true,
      pathname:""
    })
    let [removeOne, removeTwo]= removeItem 
    let removeOneStyle=this.refs[removeOne].style;
    let removeTwoStyle=this.refs[removeTwo].style;

    removeOneStyle.opacity="0";
    removeTwoStyle.opacity="0";
    removeOneStyle.top="-20%";
    removeTwoStyle.top="-20%";

    setTimeout(function(){ 
      removeOneStyle.width="0vw";
      removeTwoStyle.width="0vw";

    }, 750);

    removeOneStyle.visibility="hidden";
    removeTwoStyle.visibility="hidden";

    let itemStyle= this.refs[item].style
    let layoutStyle=this.refs.layout.style
    layoutStyle.padding="0";
    layoutStyle.gridColumnGap="0";


    this.refs[item].addEventListener('transitionend', (e)=> {
      // let label= item.toLowerCase()
      // this.setState({pathname:label})
      if(e.propertyName !=="width") return 
      setTimeout(() => {  
        let updatedPathname= "label/" + item.toLowerCase(); 
        let label= item.toLowerCase()
        if(e.propertyName ==="width") this.setState({pathname:label})
      }, 1000);
    }); item

    itemStyle.height= 100+"vh";
    itemStyle.width= 100+"vw";    
    itemStyle.zIndex="100";     
  } 


  menuBack=()=>{  
    this.setState({
      displayLabel:false,
      labelToRemove:""
    })

    let item = this.state.pathname

    let enterItem= this.state.labelStock.filter(word => word!== item);
    // this.setState({

    // })
    let [enterOne, enterTwo]= enterItem
    // console.log("removeOne, removeTwo: ", removeOne, removeTwo)
    let enterOneStyle=this.refs[enterOne].style;
    let enterTwoStyle=this.refs[enterTwo].style;

    enterOneStyle.opacity="1";
    enterTwoStyle.opacity="1";

    enterOneStyle.top="0%";
    enterTwoStyle.top="0%";

    setTimeout(function(){ 
      enterOneStyle.width="25vw";
      enterTwoStyle.width="25vw";

    }, 750);

    enterOneStyle.visibility="visible";
    enterTwoStyle.visibility="visible";

    let itemStyle= this.refs[item].style
    let layoutStyle=this.refs.layout.style
    layoutStyle.padding="0 1vw";
    layoutStyle.gridColumnGap="1.5vw";

    itemStyle.height= "50vh";
    itemStyle.width= "25vw";    
    itemStyle.zIndex="10";  
    this.setState({pathname:""})
  }

  render() { 
    var hiddenStyle={ visiblity:"hidden"};
    var displayStyle={display:"inline-block"};
    var displayFreshFood = this.state.pathname.includes("freshfood") && this.state.displayLabel
    var displayBeerQuality = this.state.pathname.includes("beerquality") && this.state.displayLabel
    var displayLocalFarm= this.state.pathname.includes("localfarm") && this.state.displayLabel

    console.log("PATHNAME: "+ this.state.pathname) 
          return (
            <div
              className={style.page}
            >             

              <div
                ref="freshfood"
                className={style.label_content}
                style={{display: this.state.pathname.includes("freshfood") && this.state.displayLabel ? 'block' : 'none' }}
              >              
                <FreshFood/>
              </div>

              <div
                ref="localfarm"
                className={style.label_content}
                style={{display: this.state.pathname.includes("localfarm") && this.state.displayLabel ? 'block' : 'none' }}
              >  
                <LocalFarm/>
              </div>

              <div
                ref="beerquality"
                className={style.label_content}
                style={{display: this.state.pathname.includes("beerquality") && this.state.displayLabel ? 'block' : 'none' }}
              >  
                <BeerQuality
                  style= {this.state.displayBeerQuality? 
                  displayStyle: hiddenStyle}
                />
               </div>

              <div
                        className={style.label_background}
                                style={{opacity: this.state.displayLabel ? 0.5: 1 }}

              >
                <div
                  id={style.presentation_video}
                > 
                <video 
                  autoPlay="autolay" 
                  muted
                  loop        
                  controls
                >
                    <source src={goldLightVideo} type="video/mp4"/>
                    <source src={goldLightVideo} type="video/ogg"/>
                    error: video module fails to display
                </video>        
                </div>
                <div 
                  ref="layout"
                  className={style.label_layout}
                >
                    {this.renderLabel()}
                </div>
              </div>      
            <BackButton
              className={style.back_button}
              visible={this.state.displayLabel}
              onClick={this.menuBack}
            >
              <img id={style.back_button_icon} src={backButtonIcon} alt=""/>
            </BackButton>
      </div> 
      )


  }
}
```

any hint would be great,
thanks

Comment: Can you provide your code, please?

Comment: Impossible to say without a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) or at least some more code. It's possible that you are calling `setState` in `render` or maybe in some event handler

Comment: Such queries needs code review. Please take some time and share the code for better reception and quick solution from community

Comment: Okay I have provided my Code

Comment: In my code I'm creating three labels that are expandable, then I put some labelComponent to overlaying them. The overlay got a button to come back on the menu. The problem is that when I then expand an another labelComponent, there is a slight lag with the old state then the new state displayed. Hence the console.log I have provided to you

Comment: Do not set state from SCU. That is causing the side effect. You should be returning a true/false from SCU method.

Comment: this is the "pathname" property that cause me trouble btw

Comment: @Mrchief thanks :), maybe you can explain what do you mean by side effect here please ? Okay I assume getSnapshotBeforeUpdate could do the job so

Comment: Hard to do it in a comment but maybe I can lay out few pointers - consider a react components' lifecycle - setState triggers a render phase. During render phase, React comes to SCU to see if it should proceed with the render or bail out. If you schedule another render (via another setState within SCU)... I guess you can see how the vicious cycle may end up doing unexpected things.

Comment: Okay I see the fundamental problem, thanks :)

Comment: If you need to calculate the nextState based on updated props/state, use [getderivedstatefromprops](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#static-getderivedstatefromprops). Or componentWillRecieveProps/componentDidUpdate if you're on older React.

Comment: @Webwoman does that help? Do you want me to post that as an answer?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188707/discussion-between-webwoman-and-mrchief).

Comment: I have provided a sandbox to illustrate my case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're adding an event listener for the `transitionend` event, which sets the state after a timeout. However, you never remove that listener, so it gets called everytime you manipulate the elements transition within the DOM, which is basically on every click event. You can fix this by removing the `transitionend` event listener after it does it's job (i.e. after it sets the state). The following code should be placed in your expand function, replacing your `this.refs[item].addEventListener(...)` logic:

```
this.addTransitionListener = listener.bind(this);
function listener(e) {
  // let label= item.toLowerCase()
  // this.setState({pathname:label})
  if (e.propertyName !== "width") return
  setTimeout(() => {
    if (e.propertyName === "width") {
      let updatedPathname = "label/" + item.toLowerCase();
      let label = item.toLowerCase()
      this.setState({
        pathname: label,
        displayLabel: true
      }, () => {
        console.log('removing listener')
        this.refs[item].removeEventListener('transitionend', this.addTransitionListener)
      })
    }
  }, 1000);
}
this.refs[item].addEventListener('transitionend', this.addTransitionListener);
```

Fork of your code with the changes can be found here: https://codesandbox.io/s/34klvpyw9p

Comment: thanks for this awesome answer, seems it works well, I will read the code asap

Comment: Glad I could help, Webwoman! If I was able to answer your question satisfactorily, please don't forget to mark it as the answer.

Comment: Yeup, I have a question please about your code, why have you use bind and all, I have tested on mine and simply add  `this.refs[item].removeEventListener(
      "transitionend",
      this.addTransitionListener
    );` inside the listenerEvent just worked, so I'm wondering if there is a special reason for your move maybe?

Comment: I was making things a bit more complicated than needed :). I was previously trying to define the listener function outside the `expand` function on the class itself, and the `setState()` call wasn't working because the class object had not been bound to the function. That code is spillover. It should also work in the way you've done it as well.

Comment: My bad :), I was using your code  when testing the change :p, effectively just put it in my code as following fail to stop the iteration

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with SCU updating state:

```
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {  
    // ... edited for brevity

            // this setState will lead to unexpected side effects
            this.setState({displayLabel:true})

    // ... edited for brevity
  }
```

Consider a React components' lifecycle - `setState` triggers a render phase. During the render phase, React comes to SCU to see if it should proceed with the render or bail out. If you schedule another render (via another setState within SCU) it'll lead to unexpected side effects.

SCU should return only `true`/`false` depending on whether you want the render to proceed or not.

If you need to calculate the `nextState` based on updated props/state, use [getderivedstatefromprops](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#static-getderivedstatefromprops). Or `componentWillRecieveProps`/`componentDidUpdate` functions if you're on older version of React.

Comment: thanks I have removed the SCU but now my state lists all the old states, 
hence I render the second time: state1 currentState, then the third time, state1 state2 currentState, etc. I can't figure out where come from this bug

Comment: What is interesting is that it does it even if I place a variable `var pathname = ""` outside my React class so I assume the problem is maybe on a other level